# If time travel is possible in the future, no matter how distant, why haven't they come back to tell us?

Tags: internal-consistency, time-travel, paradox

In a world where time travel is possible, but has not been invented *yet*, would travelers from the future come back to prove it exists?

Surely, they would bring that technology back in time to let the people of the past use it?

I have four theoretical explanations so far, **can anyone explain them in more detail, or provide other possibilities?**

1. The people decided to ban backwards time travel to prevent mass panic in the past, or to prevent possible paradoxes.
2. The people in the future went back in time to an alternate past. (Similar to the [Many worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) but with time travel).
3. The people come back in time to give the people in the past new technology, they then jump forward in time to see how humanity has progressed using this. The result is that the future they return to is different to the one they left.
4. They cannot go back in time because it has already happened, and therefore they can only go forward in time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43800/discussion-on-question-by-aric-fowler-if-time-travel-is-possible-in-the-future).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. Use the chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43800/discussion-on-question-by-aric-fowler-if-time-travel-is-possible-in-the-future

Comment: Time travel isn't possible in *worlds*; it's a feature of the *Universe* (where "Universe" is what we used to call the Multiverse).  I know that sounds picky, but it's an important concept to keep in mind.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

In all probability, we, 21<sup>st</sup> century barbarians, will not be very well loved by our 23<sup>rd</sup> century descendants.

Non-historians of that age will probably group us together with the generations of the late 20<sup>th</sup> century, and refer to us collectively in their high-school level history courses.  We are the generations who baked the earth and poisoned the seas.  We wiped out thousands of animal species and held the world hostage for almost a century under the threat of nuclear or biological annihilation.  Our insanity almost brought about human extinction and led to the Second Dark Ages, from which they are only just recovering.

"You want to give our time travel technology to those mad men?   ARE YOU NUTS?  Leave them in the past where their damage has already been done.  We don't need them coming up here to further screw up our present!"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43926/discussion-on-answer-by-henry-taylor-if-time-travel-is-possible-in-the-future-n).

Comment: Why would travelling back be the same as giving them (us) the technology? If their (our) behaviour was (is) so bad, chances are we (they) want to prevent it happening in the first place. You could go back and kill Mao, Hitler, Stalin or any other serial killer there was or even ALL of them - and you don't do that because ... they were *evil*?

Comment: Anybody intelligent enough to invent time travel is also going to be intelligent enough to know that cause and effect exists. While "going back in time to kill Hitler" is a great trope, knowledge of cause and effect would lead to the decision that doing so is a terrible idea. Killing Hitler causes more harm than good, and the inventor of time travel would know that.

Comment: I disagree with the premise of your answer.

Comment: This for some reason assumes that humanity will be more reasonable in the future. Spoiler:  It won't.

Comment: @Gloweye That's also an untrue assumption. They only have to be pretentious/self-righteous

Comment: The question nobody ever asks is *where* do you land, if you go back into the past? Everybody tacitly inserts "genidentity" into the proposition, forgetting that the very notion is, itself, just the concept of "absolute motion" in disguise. Genidentity is the relation of two events in space-time being "the same place" at "different times". If genidentity is relative, there is no such thing as "same place". What makes you think you'll land anywhere on Earth if you go back in time? You could land in the Earth's core or out in interstellar or even intergalactic space where the Earth "used to be".

Answer (score 193):

In the film [Primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(film)), there was a time travel machine that could only jump as far back as when it was first turned on.  This puts a practical limit to how far back you can jump to the point where time travel was invented in the first place.

Comment: Interesting - this could be explained in some way by quantum entanglement perhaps.  That the time machine works by principles of quantum mechanics, and the initial entangling anchors it in time and space to it's creation.

Comment: This is the way wormholes are thought to work. Due to time dilation wormholes can be used to travel through time, but only to the specific point in time in which the other end currently is. Obviously, this means that no end of the wormhole will ever be before the moment at which the wormhole was first created. Or after the one at which it was destroyed/otherwise ceased to exist. Of course that is if wormholes are possible at all, which is still unclear.

Comment: This is the obvious answer, but the question specifically says "no matter how distant"

Comment: "In the film Primer".... Ugh. You mean in Isaac Asimov's "the end of Eternity"? (The time travel machine is a single thing in a single place, and time travelling involves using it to land at that spot at a specific date. You obviously can't land before the machine was created)

Comment: @Patrice I doubt there's any connection between the two. Also End of Eternity hadn't such a law as one can see in the end.

Comment: There is reason this is an absolutely fundamental law of physics and asking a question assuming the contrary is the same as asking for a magical universe.

Comment: [This theory is not pure fiction.](http://www.hawking.org.uk/space-and-time-warps.html)

Answer (score 132):

Because the earth orbits the sun at 30km a second, the solar system is moving at 20km a second and the galaxy is moving at 230km a second! Any time travel will result in the people being dumped out into the void of space...

Maybe we need to set up some beacons to guide people to the earth through time and we can only set these up now...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43842/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-j-if-time-travel-is-possible-in-the-future-no-mat).

Comment: The question obviously implies that this minor inconvenience will be solved by an advanced enough future species that is able to do time travling...

Comment: This is not a sound argument without further explanation. Why do you assume that the time machine works on positions in the galaxy's, or cluster's, reference frame? This sounds like a nonrelativistic view, similar to the aether, which is now a fringe theory practically nobody believes in. If anything, one could complain that a position on Earth is not an inertial system, due to the involved rotations.

Comment: This answer is really intriguing. It highlights the spatial aspect of time travel: if you go back in time wanting to appear at point X on the earth's surface, you'll need to calculate exactly where point X would be at that point in time. Doing this with high precision isn't trivial. Over long time-scales (millions of years) the planetary orbits of our solar system are chaotic, meaning it would be impossible to compute precise orbital positions in the distant past. So to answer the original question, you could posit a time travel mechanism that can't work without high spatial precision.

Comment: Since the universe is expanding, the earth will never be in exactly the same place twice.....

Comment: to solve this problem the time travel machine would have to travel to the past then travel to the point earth is at that time, the longer it travels back the longer it will require to travel to earth it would require a lot of resources.

Comment: @AricFowler: Unless the earth happens to be precisely at the center of expansion ;)

Comment: @MPW https://youtu.be/DsXsJtOQnTY

Comment: @MPW ;3 in that case sign me up

Comment: See also [How can I explain that a time travelling apparatus moves itself through time but appears in the same location?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12621/29)

Comment: People got hung onto the spatial aspect of the answer. What I appreciate in it however is how it offers that time travel would rely on a complimentary piece of technology (whatever that is), and therefore can be used only back to the point in time when this auxiliary tech was first installed...

Answer (score 89):

Here's another option that is often forgotten: Time travel might need an exit system available at the destination. Since we don't have an exit system in our time, time travellers cannot visit us.

For example, time travel might be done through a wormhole whose two ends are shifted in time relative to each other, so if you enter one opening, you come back through the other opening, say, one year earlier. Going back several years would work by passing it several times, and going back is done by passing it the opposite way. Then of course you only can travel to times after that wormhole has been established.

**Edit:**

Here's a second thought that occurred to me: What if the time machine doesn't travel with you? Think of the Star Trek transporter: If people are beamed to the surface of a planet, the transporter doesn't travel with them; it remains on the ship. If they couldn't ask the people on the ship to beam them up again (say, if the transporter could only beam them away), and there were no other means to fetch them back (like shuttles), they would be stranded on the planet.

In a similar way, a time traveller that comes to our time would be stranded in our time; we simply don't have time machines to send him back into his time, and probably don't have the ability to build one in his life time even if they'd bring the plans with them, nor the energy required to operate it. Which would be a strong disincentive for anyone to visit us, unless he actually wants to live in our time — but in the latter case, he'll probably not tell us that he's a time traveller, as that will be counter productive for his plans.

Comment: Your first argument is good, but the second one has a problem; it only takes one outlier to ruin it all. While it would be a great disincentive for most, in the near infinity of humans who will exist in the future there's bound to be at least one who doesn't care about not being able to return or remaining hidden. Even among those who try to hide there could be somebody who simply makes an error. Or somebody who tries to hide something that is difficult to hide. Maybe they brought their FeelGood(tm) entertainment console thinking "it's ok if I hide it" even though it is against the rules.

Comment: @Annonymus: And what is the probability that this single outlier exactly hits our time? I mean, there are millennia past us, and from the point of view of that future person, we are only slightly less primitive than the Romans were. Maybe the Antikythera mechanism was actually built by a time traveller. Maybe it was a time traveller that sparked Greek philosophy. Maybe Jesus was a time traveller. Maybe John Titor was real.

Comment: Your first explanation actually matches up with how things would work in theoretical time travel schemes thought up by physicists, like [time travel via traversable wormholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Time_travel)--according to how wormholes would theoretically work in relativity, it would be impossible to travel back any further than when the time differential was first created between the two wormhole mouths (which would have to be done by taking one wormhole mouth on a trip at some significant fraction of the speed of light relative to the other one).

Comment: @Annonymus: there are dozens of those people amongst us today. We call them "crackpots" and lock them up. If you come here without a time machine, a bunch of talk of the future that can't be confirmed and try to convince people that you're a real time traveller, you're just going to end up in an asylum.

Comment: If you are Lex Luthor from 2200 and escape to the past hiding from the cops, you won't want to be telling that you are a time traveller so you can be detected. You will hide that fact and pretend to be a normal guy born on this age, you just took enough gadgets to take over some corporations...

Comment: All well enough, but the spirit of the question implies that this is not the issue...

Comment: @Erik See also [How do you prove you're from the future?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12348/29)

Comment: Regarding the second argument, one could teleport into the past with a time machine and perhaps a way to destroy said machine after leaving.

Answer (score 50):

Two potential solutions:

1. They are able to travel to the past, but are unable to alter it. This includes showing off their time machines or other future technology or knowledge, or anything else that might remotely change the progression of events. This is the [Novikov self-consistency principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle).
2. They have come back and told us, but their influence is retroactively expunged by *other* time-travellers charged with maintaining a consistent past.

Comment: ["Everybody kills Hitler on their first trip. I did. It always gets fixed within a few minutes, what’s the harm?"](http://www.abyssapexzine.com/archives/abyss-and-apex2007/wikihistory/).

Comment: @Schwern I don't know why, but that was extremely entertaining to read.

Comment: Sounds like time-travelling men in black lmao

Comment: @AricFowler It's a [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimePolice).

Comment: "Expunged by other time travellers"... Or by the time machine's inventor.  https://xkcd.com/716/

Comment: @rek : third potential solution, a +2,5℃ global warming sends back mankind to the neolithic age after an agony of 3 three century of civil wars.

Answer (score 31):

Ever noticed how people in time travel stories mess everything up? And then somehow by the skin of their teeth manage to put everything back to rights? Things probably don't actually work like that. About half of the time the calvary doesn't arrive in time, the answer to the riddle fails to pop into the hero's head, the match doesn't light, the green wire blows up the bomb. Time travel gives people infinite chances to mess everything up. Each chance to destroy the world plays out instantly as time travel is invented -- time travel takes all the possible spins of Russian Roulette and plays them at once.

The moment you invent time travel you fork a possible universe off, do your messy business, destroy everything and the only possible universe that still exists is the one where you didn't.

In any universes where time travel is invented the world is destroyed instantly. The fact that our world still exists can be taken as proof that we're on one of the few possible timelines where time travel doesn't, will not or cannot exist.

Comment: Not to imply this must always happen in reality(!), but as an in-universe rule chosen to explain away time travel, it's pretty great. +1 ...and hey, maybe it _does_ explain our own lack of received time-travellers ;-)

Comment: An alternative to this idea is that time travel is single use. Deep in a bunker on a ruined world a team of scientists invent time travel. They return to the Cuban missile crisis, prevent nuclear war thus creating a non-ruined world, one with no bunker, a world where the  scientists in question work on things like particle physics and normal crap.

Answer (score 29):

[@chrisj](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/51218/760) hit on the grand problem of time travel: you have to travel in time *and space*. I'd love to expand on all the ways this ties time travel to space travel.

The surface of the Earth is rotating at 0 to 465 m/s depending on your latitude. Fortunately momentum will be conserved (it must otherwise that would imply there is an absolute rest state for the universe) so when you jump you will also be traveling at that speed. However you'll be somewhere else. Even jumping 1 second back will place you 465 meters away... possibly in a brick wall. This is the least of your problems, because this assumes the Earth is standing still.

The Earth is moving around the Sun at about 30,000 m/s. Now if you jump back in time 1 second you'll be 30km away from where you started, probably either 30km inside the Earth or 30km in the air. Not good, but with some careful calculations you could construct a plane or spaceship or something? And if you want to jump back years you just make sure to jump when the Earth is in the same spot in its orbit. I have bad news.

The Solar System is rotating around the center of the galaxy at 220,000 m/s taking the Earth with it. Now if you jump back one second you'll be somewhere between 240 km and 200 km away from where you jumped, depending on which way the Earth was moving in its orbit. That's bad, but a spaceship can still fix that, right?

Let's say time travel is invented in 2216 and they want to come back to 2016 to tell us all about it! In that time the Solar System will have moved...

```
220km/s x 60 s/m x 60 m/h x 24 h/d x 365.25 d/y x 200 years
```

1,388,534,400,000 km or 1.4 trillion km or 1.4 x 10^12 km or 0.147 light years.

That's ok, your time machine is also a spaceship! You can fly back to the Earth. And you're in front of the Earth, so it will catch up to you! Well, I have some more bad news.

You came out in front of the 2016 Earth, yes, but you are continuing to move at 220 km/s around the center of the galaxy in the same direction as the 2016 Earth (the difference in angle is so slight it does not matter for rough calculations). The Earth will never catch up to you. You're going to have to fly all 0.147 ly back to the Earth.

What if you went even further back in time to give yourself more time to travel back to the Earth... now you pop out even further away from the Earth and have to travel even further to get back to it...

Basically your time machine also needs to be an interstellar space ship. Maybe time travelers have visited us.

[image: Exhibit A: A time traveler visiting Earth.]

P.S. There is a version of time travel where this is not a problem. Instead of jumping from one point in time to another, you instead speed up time. Now you are passing through every point in time. This means you are subject to the forces of gravity and held in place on the Earth.

[H.G. Wells' **The Time Machine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine) and [the time machine in Futurama](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNC06iKu28g) seem to work this way.

Comment: ...  I must say, out of all possible explanations, this one depresses me the most...

Comment: There is no preferred reference frame. It moved according to which reference frame?

Comment: @JDługosz In this case, relative to the center of the galaxy.

Comment: Which is itself moving toward the Vergo supercluster.

Comment: @JDługosz Right. I mercifully stopped before getting into that. One's brains start to leak out their ears a bit thinking about it. Point is, skipping over 200 years of planetary and galactic motion is a bad idea.

Comment: @Taegost I remembered there's an out, see the addendum I added.

Comment: @Schwern - Oh good, that makes it better!  :)

Comment: This idea about time travel was first used by Terry Carr in a short story "Brown Robert", Magazine of Fantasy & Science Fiction, July 1962. He expected it revolutionize time travel stories or stop them in their tracks. It didn't. Writers ignored it & kept on writing time travel stories the way they always had done. It only applies to time travel where there is a pure shift in time without any spatial motion. Which seems unlikely.

Comment: You're missing JDługosz's point. The entire idea of this post is nonrelativistic! Why would the galaxy's reference frame be better than any other? If anything, you could complain that a position on Earth is not a real inertial system, due to the involved rotations. In any case, if you see gravity as something that curves space-time and all inertial systems as equally valid, expecting that time machines naturally care about the galactic center is absurd.

Comment: @Vandroiy A time machine cares about the galactic center because it cares (rather its passenger cares) about the position of the Earth relative to when they jumped, and the galaxy's gravity affects that. If you use the Earth's position when you make the jump, in the past or future doesn't matter, as your frame of reference and plot the motion of the Earth over the 200 years you will see it undergoing all sorts of relative motion due to the gravity of the Sun, the galaxy, and it's galactic group. The time machine skips all that, so it winds up where the Earth was when it jumped.

Comment: @Schwern That's not what a frame of reference is. If you use the Earth's position as your frame of reference, the Earth never moves in your given frame of reference. This whole construct is not a valid argument unless you define a universal way to not move. But that sounds like a Newtonian world with an aether, which doesn't seem to be the world we live in.

Comment: @Vandroiy You don't use the Earth's continual position, but the Earth's position at the moment of the jump. Even if you assume that point retains its momentum over time, it won't follow the Earth's, and Sun's, and galaxy's orbital curves and rotations. There is no doubt that the Earth moves relative to its initial position in 200 years. To invert the argument, why would the universe contrive to place the time machine at the same point relative to the center of the spinning Earth?

Comment: nitpick: Earth _rotates_ around its axis but _revolves_ around the Sun (technically the barycenter of the solar system but close enough).

Comment: @Schwern While I'll try myself at an alternative, the burden of proof should be on the answer, because I'm not the one making a prediction. But for a solution without the reference frame issue, how about assuming that the time-machine simply moves through space-time as curved by gravity, without interacting? It should end up somewhere in, on, or at least close to Earth. Calculate the traveled time smartly to end up on the surface. This requires no extra parameter and doesn't create potential energy from nowhere.

Comment: @Vandroiy Oh, there's all sorts of ways to violate conservation of energy with a time machine. As for gravity... sure, you can say your time machine only interacts with gravity/spacetime. But if you don't interact with the other forces the Earth will rotate under you. Also you'll fall towards the center of the Earth and oscillate around the center. Write it up as an answer and we can analyze it there.

Comment: @Schwern That is why I said "Calculate the traveled time smartly". Nobody claimed that the time-machine can safely travel any amount of time from any location. A quick and expensive solution is to start and exit in low-earth orbit, where on exit you fire thrusters to correct any remaining velocity deviation. But again, I'm not building a time machine, nor do I want to make assumptions. The point is just that the answer makes assumptions that need not hold. (I'm not claiming to have any answer myself, just wanted to explain what JDługosz meant as I felt he was misunderstood.)

Comment: See also [How can I explain that a time travelling apparatus moves itself through time but appears in the same location?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12621/29)

Answer (score 23):

### Just because they can doesn't mean they will.

Most people have phones; why do they not call people in other continents to tell them about their phone? Many people have cars, why don't they drive to places that do not have cars?

Despite the simplicity of this argument, it gives you the answers;

1. They don't care about people from the past.
2. They do not want to give people from the past time travel
3. They are not allowed to give people time travel technology.

Comment: If you drive to a place where there is already a car, you'd be in a car accident.

Comment: Ehi TrEs-2b I have a SE account I wanted you to know that :)

Comment: No, if time is far enough to infinitely, then they must always has some bad guy break the law to travel back and leave a high technology trace. And the technology can be advanced enough to tell us all the story.

Answer (score 22):

**Option 1: Time travel is a one-time deal**

Let's suppose time travel allows you meaningfully alter the past. By jumping back in time you're erasing the future you came from, leading to the good old fashioned grandfather paradox. Let's just sidestep that - You're physically in the past, so let's just assume you're now part of the past.

Kill Hitler, save Lenin and  Franz Ferdinand, do whatever you want. You've now altered the time-stream such that the invention of time travel most likely happens at a different moment, if it happens at all. If the new inventors of time travel jump back the same thing will happen, either erasing you if they jumped earlier or erasing their own discovery if they jumped in after you.

If one of these jumps alters the timeline so that time travel isn't discovered, then it'll stay that way forever. If anyone from anytime can travel to any point in the past, then there's effectively an infinite chance this has happened. In the same way that people say it's statistically certain we live in a simulation, I say it's statistically certain we live in a universe were time-travel was permanently un-invented.

**Option 2: Time travel is for forensics and archaeology**

Maybe time travel doesn't even send you back in time - Maybe it just lets you see the past exactly as it was, like a kind of reverse Minority Report. I don't really have much to say about this one - It avoids all the problems of causality because it's non-interactive, but aside from perfect reconstruction of the past it's pretty dull. Great for documentaries, bad for trying to hunt dinosaurs.

Comment: Third option, a +2,5℃ global warming sends definitely back mankind to the neolithic age after a long agony of 3 three century of civil war. So many technologies will never be discovered ever, including time travel.

Comment: @user2284570 Conspiracy mode: In 2773 a radical religious sect seeks to destroy earths atmospheric control nanites and return Mother Gaia to the natural order. Their plan: To travel to the past, and sew the seeds of war and strife to prevent a parasitic mankind from controlling nature.

Comment: Yes, but for my case, the first of those centuries civil wars affecting worldwide had already started *(with 3 previous ones that only affect the local area)*. So it’s not purely fictional. Though I agree the root cause is hidden for those who don’t read ᴘᴀᴍ’s reports. And after re‑reading the question, I found that kind of answer will be out of scope.

Answer (score 16):

I think there's something subtle missing from the "how do you account for Earth's motion" explanation: which reference frame does your time machine use?  Sure, the Earth is rotating, but that's relative to the Earth's center.  It's also orbiting the sun, but that's relative to the sun.  That's also orbiting the galactic center, but that's relative to the galaxy.  The galaxy is moving through space relative to other galaxies or relative to the CMB.

So which reference frame does your time machine move relative to?  How does it establish that reference frame and track it through time?  Reference frames are sort of arbitrary, you need to tie them to something physical.  And maybe that's how you resolve the problem.  Maybe your time machine isn't a vehicle, it's a portal and a portal needs two ends.  Only the two ends aren't separated by space, they're separated by time (or both).

So why aren't time travelers coming in from the future?  Because we haven't built the time machine yet.

Comment: I was about to give a similar answer. This is a theoretically plausible method, assuming that it's possible to create stable portable wormholes and that it's possible to survive a trip through one. Establish a wormhole with one end in your lab and the other end at the event horizon of a black hole. Let it sit for a fixed amount of time (say 10 years), then finally move the black hole end into your lab beside the other end. Going through one way sends you 10 years into the future, and other sends you 10 years into the past, or into a black hole if you try to go too far back.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment..?

Comment: "So why aren't time travelers coming in from the future? Because we haven't built the time machine yet." I have seen this explanation several times, and i find it quite interesting. The idea of only being ablt to go back to when the portal was built is a good one.

Comment: See also [How can I explain that a time travelling apparatus moves itself through time but appears in the same location?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12621/29)

Comment: See the difference between inertial and non-inertial reference frames. Consider how the distinction changes physics calculations. Hand-waving with "you can have any reference frame you want" doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

We are the ALPHA-TIMELINE.

Just as space expands, the dimension of time expands as well, the process of which we perceive as the passing of time. We are at the very edge of time, any new moment that happens hasn't existed before it happened. History is the coordinates of time we leave behind.

As the progression of time only happens because of the "pressure" that the past exerts on time, everytime you travel backwards in time, you collapse the present; once you travel back, the time you have travelled too is the new edge of time (so, no travelling back to the future).
[For added weirdness: Maybe the collapse only happens locally. When you travel back, you only reset those parts that you have an effect on, causing this part of spacetime to be out of synch with the rest of the universe].

**There are no travelers from the future, because the future has yet to happen.**

Comment: You're saying "time traveling is impossible", but that's not relevant to the question. The question is postulating "time traveling is possible => why XXX". The fact that time traveling is possible is not debatable for this world-building question.

Comment: @AnoE I'm saying that time travel is only possible in one direction, from our point of view (the "edge of time"), and any direction from any other point. In Addition, the first paragraph answers the question, the second paragraph is only meant to provide additional flavour text. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the formating.

Comment: I kind of understand your words, but it is hard to follow what you mean. "The future has yet to happen" - does not compute. :)

Comment: @AnoE : The question was created using a given assumption that time traveling is possible.  However, TheSexyMenhir came up with a brilliant in-universe explanation why time travel involving the future may be impossible, even if time travel (to the past) is impossible.

Comment: "time travel involving the future may be impossible, even if time travel (to the past) is impossible" there may be one `im` too many in there. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Time travel to the past requires both a sending device in the future and a receiving device in the past. Without both in place, no backwards time travel is possible. It could be that no stable wormhole will form, or attempting travel without a receiver will always result in the traveler being atomized. No matter how far technology advances, nothing is able to overcome the need for a receiving device. Thus the earliest time period to which a time traveler can travel will be the first successful invention of the time machine, which, of course, hasn't happened yet.

This means that whoever invents the first working receiver will be inundated by travelers from innumerable points in the future who've come to witness the birth of time travel, and/or the earliest possible era they can travel to.

So, if you invent a time machine, make sure you have a lot of receivers built before switching **any** of them on. Or don't ever tell anyone or record anywhere that you made one.

---

A couple alternate explanations:

- Only a few attempts at backwards time travel were *ever* attempted throughout all of (future) history. Some were successful, but for one reason or another they always seemed like catastrophic failures from the sender's perspective. No one ever returned or sent back data, and no one managed to leave a clear indicator to the future that they had succeeded. So time travel was determined to be impossible, and every few thousand years when some nut-job tried again, the same basic result occurred, keeping time travel in the "impossible" category.
- Each trip back in time actually creates an alternate universe, with the original universe continuing to exist. From the original universe's perspective, time travel is unsuccessful and is instead a way of destroying matter and energy. We are in the original universe, so no time travelers have *arrived* in our universe because they actually arrive in an alternate one. The alternate universe's history is identical to ours until the moment a time traveler arrives in it, and which point the events begin to diverge.

Comment: One conceit that has appeared in a few works is that the receiver and the sender are actually the exact same device, so no one can use a particular time machine to travel back to a time before the machine was first activated.

Answer (score 9):

There are various theories for this, the most common being

> Backward time travel creates a parallel timeline where it happened, the prime timeline remaining untouched.

This prevents paradoxes, it also means that the primary timeline can never have examples of backward time travel. It also means that you can never go home, never undo the damage you've done, only get slowly further and further away from the world you knew.

Another popular option being

> Time travel is only possible as far back as the first implementation of the technology.

The best known of these being under the wormhole theory. Which allows you to create wormholes for time travel but you can't go back to a point before you created the first wormhole.

There's also the classic

> It happens all the time, but my mate says the government covers it up.

I think this needs no further comment.

But there's also the more important:

> How would you know?

What has been has always been from your point of view.

Answer (score 8):

Because you can't interact with time, in the general sense.  Time travel isn't like going to Disneyland and stading in line for all the cool rides, arguing with the guy that cut in front of you, or sweating future sweat all over the past.

It's more like going to an animated wax museum and watching the same script play out over and over and over again - you can change perspective, pay attention to this or that, but you can't change any of it.

Future time travelers use the technology to study the past for what it was and not how it is portrayed by biased writers.  In this way, future time travelers are able to help future soceities learn from the past's mistakes and truly make the future a better place.

Answer (score 8):

The one remotely plausible mechanism for time travel is through "frame dragging" with a massive rotating object. The purpose built device is known as a "T machine" after Frank Tippler, who first proposed it, but it may be possible to have a similar effect using a rapidly rotating neutron star or black hole.

Essentially what happens is the rotating object bends space-time in such a fashion that light cones are "tipped" and point to "elsewhen", outside of the 45 degree boundary defined by the speed of light. The illustration demonstrates how this is done:

[image]

[image]

There are a number of different assumptions you can make (and since no one has a working T machine to test it on, many of these ideas are equally plausible).

Number one: you cannot go any farther back in time than the creation of the T machine in the first place. Since we are talking about an artificially maintained cylinder of neutronium rotating at nearly the speed of light, this isn't a project that is going to be carried out anytime in the near future (or at least *our* near future).

Number two: moving into the past or future creates a new "timeline", and this timeline simply sees you start spiralling around the T machine and vanishing, never to return.

Number three: Since travelling in time is essentially travelling to "elsewhen", you have left our universe. This is related to number two, since there is no guarantee that the tipped light cones will actually be pointing back to your starting point. Even in the unlikely event that your light cone is pointed back to our universe, it might not be pointed back to our region of space, or to our current time. Popping back in existence in our universe one billion years in the future or one billion light years away has some obvious problems for the time traveller.

Finally, most of these ideas are based on the assumption that you can equally access the T machine after travelling through to "otherwhen". Passing through the field of tipped light cones and emerging in an empty universe where there is no corresponding T machine is going to be a huge problem.

Comment: Tipler's idea is outdated, it's been proven that in the theory of relativity it wouldn't work unless the cylinder were literally infinite in length--see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipler_cylinder). But alternate theoeretical methods of time travel have been found in relativity which could work in a finite region, like [traversable wormholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Time_travel)--you can read more about this in books written by physicists for a general audience, like "Black Holes and Time Warps" by Kip Thorne or "Time Travel and Warp Drives" by Everett and Roman.

Comment: i did not ask for how time travel might work, considering that my first sentence in the question starts with "In a world where time travel is possible..."

Comment: @Aric Fowler - But the method may determine the answer, see my comment on celtschk's answer above.

Comment: Point taken, this could provide some insight into the answer

Answer (score 8):

An option that has not been mentioned in the main answers (only found in the last one by colmde, when I thought it would not have been raised) is that such time travel discovered in the far distant future may not allow to travel back in time to where we are now. Probably not due to physics laws if it is able to travel back in time, but due to economics.

So, traveling back a week, is affordable to almost anyone.

Traveling back a month, would be a severe hit to your economy but generally doable.

Traveling back some years is something only governments or big corporations can afford.

Traveling back hundreds of years, you would need the energy of dozens of suns to power your travel machine, thus it is "impossible" even though time travel is allowed and routinely performed in this universe.

Actually, it is uncommon that it would cost the same to travel back 1 day than 100 years (but I don't know the details of the time machine that is discovered in that distant future). Moreover, the power needed to travel back probably isn't linear to the time traveled but likely quadratical.

Answer (score 7):

I think it was Larry Niven that came up with the solution:

If altering the past is possible then the means to do so will never be discovered.

The thing is, if time travel is possible someday someone will tamper with the past.  Somebody else will tamper with the past and so on.  The only stable state is the one in which the time machine is never discovered.  Thus any observer in a universe with a time machine gets reset out of existence and thus all observers see no time machine.

Note that this does not preclude what I call time roads--something where the time travel technology doesn't travel in time and thus you can only reach a point while it already existed.  Such a device can't be reset out of existence.  (Example, Robert L. Forward, *Timemaster*--time travel was attained by relatavistically altering the relative age of the ends of a wormhole.  Take one end to the stars and bring it back, hop through and you move a fixed distance through time.)

Answer (score 6):

After inventing this technology, they tested it by going back to a point that is still in our future, activated some paradoxes, and **wiped themselves out before they could send the information, people, etc. farther back.**

Alternatively, they did figure out how to send information back in time, but they used quantum entanglement and other such effects to do it, so **we have to wait until we've built the receivers** for those messages before we notice.  Analogously, we can send a radio signal deep into a forest, but if there's nobody in there with an appropriately constructed receiver, they won't notice the information being sent to them.

Comment: "activated some paradoxes, and wiped themselves out before they could send the information, people, etc. farther back." Thereby causing another paradox! If they never sent the stuff back, then they couldn't wipe themselves out, so they could send the stuff back, then they'd wipe themselves out, and is it just me or is anyone else feeling dizzy. AFAICT this paradox is usually invoked to ensure things **do** happen (albeit without explaining how it 'first' happened), not _don't_.

Comment: @underscore_d Yep, and by the time you stop spinning and the loop breaks, the story's over.  For less confusion, the wipeout event triggered by the paradox could have its effect *after* the moment they sent someone back ("we started experimenting with time travel, and then strange things started happening, and then this...") but *before* they can run another test.

Answer (score 6):

Time travel is powerful. So powerful that you don't want those other guys to have access to it. So you use time travel to get rid of them. (unless, of course, they get rid of you first)

The timeline can only sustain, at most, one time traveler, and he's not sharing.

(credit for the basic idea goes to Erfworld fanon, regarding the magic school of retconjuration)

Comment: Basically, one who can travel in time becomes (a) god, and there can be only one.

Comment: In using time travel to get rid of the people you don't want to have access to time travel, it's also perfectly plausible that you rid yourself of the motivation behind inventing time travel in the first place, resulting in time travel never being invented, resulting in those people persisting, ... These time travel paradoxes give me headaches.

Answer (score 6):

They already did.

And THIS happened.

**We are already living** in the end product of time traveler meddling.  It didn't go so well, so they stopped doing it.  Mostly.

As for why it isn't widely known, please - be my guest.  Start telling people.

Comment: Under this answer, the miracle-performers (saints etc.) might really be time travelers.

Answer (score 6):

1.) **It will not be humans as we know them now that develop time travel.**

From the Sagan Series: [The Frontier is Everywhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oY59wZdCDo0):

> It will not be we who reach Alpha Centauri and the other nearby stars.
>   It will be a species very like us, but with more of our strengths and
>   fewer of our weaknesses, more confident, farseeing, capable, and
>   prudent.

I think the same concept applies to time travel. We're quickly approaching [the singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) and as such, people will either become exceedingly enlightened and abandon much of what once made them such petty creatures or they will [cease to exist](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/faculty/vinge/misc/singularity.html).

The "humans" (more likely to be cyborgs) of this future will understand the long-reaching effects of their actions and won't want to interfere with the past if it might cause unforeseeable consequences to the future.

2.) **Humans of the future have already been wiped out**

It can't be said that humans have passed the [Great Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Filter) yet. We're still living in tumultuous times. We still might wipe ourselves out. No humans in the future means no one to come visit us.

3.) **Alternate time lines**

As others have mentioned, it may be the case that alternate timelines exist or branch when someone tries to change something in the past. This prevents time paradoxes.

4.) **We haven't made any receiving devices yet**

As others have mentioned, it might be the case that time travel requires receiving devices that we haven't developed yet. It's easy to calculate where the Earth will be 200 years from now, so that won't be a problem, but no device to travel to might be.

5.) **There might be infinite timelines for time travelers to go to and we're one of the infinite that don't get traveled to**

Maybe time travelers can travel to any of an infinite number of time lines. the chances of one landing on our time line is infinitesimal. There are trillions of years for them to travel through and trillions of universes, but maybe only a few time travelers so far. The odds of them showing up during the last 5,000 years of our recorded history out of the trillions of years that our timeline will exist are very slim.

Comment: I think you are correct with theory #2.  Humans are a parasite to this planet and it does not take much of a leap to believe that we destroy ourselves in the next century or two.

Answer (score 4):

There was a short story by Larry Niven named "Rotating Cylinders and the Possibility of Global Causality Violation", inspired by a mathematics/physics paper of the same name by J. Frank Tipler.  In the story, archaeologists investigating the artifacts of an extinct alien civilization have discovered documents describing the theory of these time machines, along with at least one incomplete prototype.

One of the characters theorizes that the universe itself somehow acts to prevent the activation of any such devices, in order to prevent any violation of its physical laws.  In the instance of the extinct alien race being investigated, I believe that the sun of their star system had gone nova before they could complete the device.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to address the second option on your list, [Many Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation), in more detail. In my opinion, it is the only physically-sound explanation for how time travel could exist while no effects from it would be visible. That said, Many Worlds is itself a bit of physics-woo, so make of it what you will.

The basic concept of Many Worlds is that for every possible outcome of an event, the universe splits, and both (or however many outcomes are possible) occur.

It is closely related to the concept of [Quantum Immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_suicide_and_immortality), which comes out of the application of Many Worlds to [Schrodinger's Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat). In that thought experiment, a cat is left in an undermined state inside a box, either alive or dead. The primary issue is that, if the cat is in an undetermined state, what does the cat perceive before the box is opened? Many Worlds suggests the cat experiences both continued life and death; Quantum Immortality is the suggestion the cat would merely experience continued life, thus becoming immortal.

This is related to time travel in that it suggests every *possible* event, no matter how incredibly unlikely, occurs. Considering phenomena such as [zero point energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy), where probability is the main factor preventing absurd random occurrences (and entropy, the addressing of which is beyond this answer), the word "possible" can effectively be removed from that statement: **every** event occurs.

Now, imagine some time traveler returns from 2222 to now. Let's presume the time machine comes with them, for the sake of discussion. What is the probability that a time machine and a time traveler appears in your front yard in the next hour? It's insanely - nearly impossibly - unlikely. But following certain conditions and making certain assumptions, it is *possible* for that to happen. Meaning in some universe, it *must* happen.

Now, there is an issue with this, and it is where the cat returns. From your point of view, the probability of that occurrence is so vanishingly small it is easy to ignore. People and time machines do not just materialize out of thin air. But the probability from the *time traveler's point of view* is substantially higher. If the trip does not fail and he is not killed in the process, his only option is to appear in your front yard.

It's worth pointing out this would suggest probability can be "localized" to a given person. Again, that's well beyond the point I am making.

Because of the difference in the probability of outcomes between you and the time traveler, we end up in a case where the time traveler is effectively routed to a specific branch of time where he and his machine popped into being. You and I never experience this because it is so insanely unlikely that just in a pure probabilistic sense, we end up in some other branch of time. However, at least some number of you in other branches of time *do* see the time traveler. There's just *many more* of you that do not experience a time traveler appearing in their yard.

It is also worth pointing out this would mean temporal paradoxes are actually impossible to form, since upon going back in time, the time traveler would be entirely decoupled from their own origins. They effectively just spontaneously came into existence remembering "their" future.

---

So to summarize all that physics-woo, the Many Worlds interpretation applied to time travel would suggest it is merely very unlikely we end up in the same universe as any given time traveler. It's not impossible, but so insignificantly unlikely we can go about our lives with it never actually happening.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone arriving from 'not now' (either direction) would, by so arriving, automatically create an alternate timeline to 'contain' them.  So there may in fact be alternate histories in which people are aware of time travelers.  But we are all stuck in the original timeline and never get to see anyone arrive.

*[On a side note: nearly every depiction of time travel is impossible because anything which travels, by arriving or leaving, automatically violates conservation of energy.  The only depiction which stands a chance of avoiding this is the 'Terminator' kind in which pieces of space-time - presumably of the same energy content (though how is this enforced?) - are exchanged between source and destination]*

Comment: Why would we expect time travel to conserve energy? Conservation of energy is just an observation, there's no entity that actually enforces it. Physically, as far as I understand it most explanations rely on time symmetry (see ["Why is energy conserved?"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108088/why-is-energy-conserved) on Physics SE) and I don't see why that couldn't be broken as a result of time travel.

Comment: Glad to see this argument used. It's one I have maintained for some time now. As a consequence, time travel would be discontinued. Time travellers would disappear from their home timeline and never be seen again. The original timeline never benefits from time travel. Yet it bears the cost and effort of making time machines and losing the people who become time travellers.

Comment: About your side-note: conservation of energy applies to closed systems. If time travel can only happen in a closed system, yes conservation of energy will apply. If time travel happens in open system, ones that aren't closed, then conservation of energy not apply. In fact, no more than it does to motion through space. Fantastic answer about time travellers lost in an infinity of alternative histories!

Comment: Where in the _Terminator_ franchise do any time-travelling objects or "pieces of space-time" get "exchanged"? I might've just missed it, but it doesn't sound familiar at all. I guess it was called the "time displacement mechanism", but was that ever revealed to actually exchange matter? I always just assumed it meant the user was displaced in time, nothing more elaborate. Knowing what expanded-universe stuff is typically like, there's probably an entire book on this that I've not read, heh.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. Time Travel only goes one way. It's called cryogenics and right now it generally has a 100% fatality rate.

The problem with this question is that it makes a faulty assumption. It assumes time exists. A better approach is to ask oneself, "What is time?"

Simply put, time is perception. It's possible to perceive time at an incredible rate. Don't believe me? You're living proof. To something like an idea or concept that stands outside of the universe's perception, the all of reality might happen in an instance. It isn't slow, it just perceives events at a different perception. Another aspect is causality. Humans evolved in a way to create assumptions. We assume a beginning and an end. This instinctively creates a range. Here's another fundamental flaw. The universe isn't a dog or cat. It's timeless and infinite. It's not old, because that would require that it didn't exist at some point. Scientist busy themselves trying desperately to prove a beginning. This is because the other option is infinitely terrifying. The universe is in a way, its own cosmic horror. It defies reason. It is the absents of reason. In short, it's hell.

Time works along the same misconception. If time existed, it would mean that at every point that the universe exists, there is a backup. The problem with this, is that there isn't a place to store something like that. Infinite isn't a number. It's a concept. It's something that isn't big. It just is. Causality is a human construct. If we didn't have memories or our memories were a jumble, time wouldn't be a concept at all.

Instead of thinking of time as something to be traveled, it's more accurate to realize that there is just motion. We build our own time. The universe won't be bent to anything's will. Even something like an elevated idea can't undo an event. When a lightbulb breaks, you can only replace it.

So in short, time doesn't exist. A lot of people are making a whole lot of money creating a comforting lie. The sooner the elites stop looking for comfort the sooner we can get back to fixing real issues.

P.S. I'm sorry if this seems like a downer. I'm not trying to insult anyone. If this is pure science fiction speculation, then I have missed the point entirely and I apologize.

Comment: This is a great post, however it does not answer the question "**if time travel is possible in the future**, no matter how distant, why havent they come back to tell us?"

Comment: On that note, what if it requires that the device exist on both sides of the jump to work? Maybe you need a machine to jump to?

Comment: That is a valid point, and it is one of the possibilities i am considering.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with the following sentences, can you clarify? "If time existed, it would mean that at every point that the universe exists, there is a backup. The problem with this, is that there isn't a place to store something like that." Specifically, why can't there be a "beginning" of things, and what do you mean with "storing"?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the very first time traveller started out now, in 2016, going back some twenty years.

When he got there, they asked him who was running for president in 2016.  When he tried to tell them it was Hillary Clinton versus Donald Trump, they put him in a quiet room where he couldn't do anybody any harm.

Comment: now he gets the pleasure of saying 'i told you so'

Answer (score 3):

## It's too hard to find parking

Time travel requires you to specify a time **and a location**.
As you would guess, specifying an exact location is quite important. If you appear 100 meters in the air, you die. If you appear 2 meters underground, you die. if you appear on a wall, you die. Would you risk it?

A time machine can't be expected to know what it means to land "in someone's back yard", it needs exact coordinates, with the axis starting from, i don't know, probably the center of the universe or something.

As soon as we start recording exact coordinates of safe landing spaces on earth, people from the future will appear.

[image]

"I'll just go around the century again, I can't find a spot"

Comment: So develop a time machine with a parachute and appear _somewhere_ between 100 meters in the air and a few kilometers in the air. Should be easy enough to fall somewhere in the range where you can gently fall to the ground with a parachute.

Comment: If you can land in a few kilometers' range you're in fantastic shape. But it's an infinitesimally small target to hit when you try to shoot blind

Answer (score 2):

Ok lets first break apart your questions:

**Question 1**:

> ...would travelers from the future come back to prove it exists?

**Answer 1**: Why would they bother, what possible motivation would they have for this.  They know it is possible and exists they wouldn't need to prove it to the past.

**Question 2**:

> Surely, they would bring that technology back in time to let the
>   people of the past use it?

**Answer 2**: See Answer 1

Now lets look at your theoretical explanations for why this might not occur:

> I have four theoretical explanations so far, can anyone explain them
>   in more detail, or provide other possibilities?

**Theory 1**:

> The people decided to ban backwards time travel...

**Response:** People ban lots of things and still people do those things, so most likely some people would still do that thing.

**Theory 2**:

> The people in the future went back in time to an alternate past.

**Responses**: Personally I've always viewed alternate pasts as a hack trope of time travel plots. I comprehend alternate futures, but the past seems rather fixed from the POV of whatever *when* you are.  Besides if this were the case then it doesn't particularly matter.

**Theory 3**:

> The people come back in time ... then jump forward in time... they
>   return to is different to the one they left.

**Response**: This is basically the classic many worlds/alternate timelines trope. Again if their present changes, it is still our relative future so no big deal from our POV.

**Theory 4**:

> They cannot go back in time ...therefore they can only go forward in
>   time.

**Response**: So basically.... they are us.  Traveling forward in time and never back.

But have you considered that perhaps they have and do.  Maybe they have been here maybe they have marched up the steps of the white house and declared that they are from the future and presented us with a time machine. Maybe they've created countless paradoxes.

Here is the funny thing about time travel.
We do it all the time without thinking about it, albeit in one direction.  If we could turn around and go "the other way" we would un-perceive things going in reverse. Funny thing about this is that in-fact there is no reason to believe that we are in fact going in the "right" direction we may live in a back-wards universe with crazy things happing like, gravity pulling things together, light coming out of stars and and people being "born".

Now...if we could jump back or forward in time but then continue forward in time at our normal temporal pace.. ah this would be what we think of as time travel, with that concept, there are basically four primary possibilities I can see.

- Time travel is only possible in one direction. Period. (borring)
- Time travel is possible *(at this point we make an assumption that if time travel is possible it is impossible to avoid all paradoxes)*

  - There is some mechanism outside of the known universe to prevent paradoxes from forming.
  - The universe is always in a state of paradox but because we are in the paradox we are unaware of it
  - Any universe in which time travel is possible is a universe that will ultimately destroy itself before it exists.

Personally I like this last option... unfortunately this also means that the first option is also true.

So the point of all this is that. In a universe where time travel is possible there is no reason to believe that we would know it when we saw it even if it were sitting right in front of us.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the ways we have hypothesized to time travel require that the ability to time travel exist in the time you are trying to get back to. In other words, if Time travel is possible, because we haven't invented it yet, they can't get back to us. It's really kinda simple ^.^

Answer (score 1):

There's a law that says it's illegal to travel into the past. Governments fear that even the smallest time travel may alter the present and cause unforeseeable consequences. The time travel technology is in the hands of so few people that it's possible to enforce the law.

Comment: Like Star Trek's [Temporal Prime Directive](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Temporal_Prime_Directive).

Answer (score 1):

You can only send energy, not solid matter. Eventually future people figure that out and build receiving devices, and two way time travel is possible from that point forward. They still split the timeline of course which every trial...

The static coming out of your radio and TV are the wails of trillions of doomed time travelers; all trying to get someones, anyone's attention.

Answer (score 1):

I quite liked how the 2006 film *Deja Vu*, staring Val Kilmer and Denzel Washington, handled "Time Travel" of sorts.  I don't think it's a spoiler at all to say they could strictly view as an observer - although from essentially any conceivable angle, and for a very limited time into the recent past.  Watch the movie, some aspect of this concept might prove interesting for you to adapt to your needs!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, no one brought up a simple fact that **it would cost more energy to jump further** in time or space. Just because you can jump 2 feet on a pogo stick, doesn't mean you could cross a city on it. Similarly, lets say that time travel is invented circa 2300 and there are ways to deal with the usual paradoxes forecast in SF stories.

Going against the normal flow of time probably needs a huge amount of energy even for short hops. Moving back around a week or two might be close to the monthly energy output of entire world circa 2010, and jumping back a couple of months would be close to monthly output of the world in 2300 (which presumably has overall increased, but also humans are far more efficient with it).

In such a case, world government (UN or descendants) may collectively save up enough power to jump back a month and prevent/prepare for previously unforeseen emergencies. That would be a great use of time travel to help in the era that it exists, and get great acceptance from the public. But, even allowing a jump of a couple of years would be prohibitively expensive and hence infeasible - not to mention the completely insane idea of a 200 year time leap. And this is excluding any necessary budgeting for follow up interventions to solve time paradoxes and unwanted ripple effects of the journey.

Comment: I think [Angel's answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/51377/4811) from yesterday already covered this.

Answer (score 1):

> In a world where time travel is possible, but has not been invented yet, would travelers from the future come back to prove it exists?

In theory, yes.

Here is the basis of that answer:
According to certain texts, this has actually happened.  People have seen the future, and even interacted with beings that have done things in the future.  Then, these time travelers have gone back in time and reported it to people.  The result is that their observations have been recorded in the ancient texts that report such things.

Another result is most of a world remaining unconvinced.

> Surely, they would bring that technology back in time to let the people of the past use it?

Not quite so surely.

You're assuming that the people who are doing the traveling have control over the ability to initiate the travels, and they can effectively teach others, and that others will trust the messengers enough to follow the available instructions.

Another possibility is that the combination (of all of these things) is not entirely true.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said the distance the Earth has rotated, traveled around the sun and the solar system traveled around the universe would seemingly make it impossible not to end up in the deep void of space.

However.....

How about only being able to go back to certain points in time? Since the Earth would need to be in the exact same position (or nearby if you are in some sort of spaceship) you only have a window of x amount of time which you can travel back to. Assume that the Earth is in the exact same position every 2,500 years (I made that number up, I'm sure it is wrong). You would be able to travel back in increments of 2,500 years +- any amount of time in which it is feasible to get back to Earth on your ship.

We wouldn't know about it because we weren't in that window when someone was traveling (it was banned or forgotten or people decided not to use it to come to us or whatever.) Basically time travel isn't as easy as go to wherever and whenever you want.

(How do you think the pyramids were built? Clearly people came from the future with their technology and built it.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to worldbuilders! :) I do have a question about this - you've said "the Earth would need to be in the exact same position". The question is, same position relative to what? If it's the same position relative to the Sun, then there seems to be no reason for this to be the case as the Sun is also moving relative to the centre of the galaxy (and pretty much everything really). The Sun's orbit only intersects itself once every ~225-250 million years, ignoring the fact that the galaxy itself is probably moving relative to the galaxy cluster...

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Relative to everything. This is obviously assuming that the universe is not infinite and at some point Earth will end up at exactly the same location that it was in, in space, in the past. (Basically at some point there isn't something bigger that is orbiting as well). I made up the number 2,500 off the top of my head. If you could only travel in increments of 250 million years that would explain even more why we have not been visited. It may be that its only possible to travel in increments of billions of years and by then humans may have died off.

Comment: An advanced enough society which can travel in time will certainly have zero problems with either a) calculating where the earth was XXX years ago and adjusting accordingly or b) implementing the time travel in such a way that it uses *earth* as a fixed frame of reference. As many others, this answer does not address the question "if t.t. is possible, for what reasons would people not go back" but instead simply says "t.t. is not possible".

Comment: @AnoE I'm not suggesting time travel is impossible. Rather I'm suggesting it would be impossible to travel across such a distance of space in no time at all. Essentially you could only travel through time to a time when Earth was in its same position which could only be possible every x amount of years. You can't necessarily travel through time (at least backwards or faster forward than we do automatically) and space at the same time which could mean that no matter what frame of reference is used this could be true.

Comment: I understand what you want to say, but it does not make sense to talk about "the earth going back to same position". In relation to what? The sun? The center of the galaxy? The center of our galaxy cluster? Center of the universe? If you have to pick a frame of reference, you'd pick earth itself (including its rotation around itself of course), which would be physically completely equal to picking any other frame (like the sun). All in the context of time travel being possible, as posted by the question, of course.

Comment: Can i add that the universe is expanding, so the earth will never be in the same place twice. It takes 225 to 250 million years for the earth to orbit around the centre of the milky way, and added to that all galaxies are expanding outwards, meaning that it is impossible for the earth to be in the same place twice (unless at some point the universe started contracting again, however evidence shows that at the moment it is _accelerating_ and not likely to stop). http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/10/111004-nobel-prize-physics-universe-expansion-what-is-dark-energy-science/

Answer (score 0):

Change something in the past , then in the future you will have nothing to change in the past.

1)Jimmy invents time travel in 2700

2)Jimmy travels back in 2016 to tell everyone about it,
In 2016 everybody knows already about time travel.

3)Since time travel already exists then jimmy had no reason to invent it in 2700

4)Since Jimmy never invented time travel then he never traveled in the past

5)Cause jimmy didn't  travel in the past nobody knew about time travel in 2016

6)As a result everything eliminates itself

It's exactly the same thing as traveling in the past and killing your young self , nullifies itself and simply doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

**....or provide other possibilities?**

5 : Timetraveller's come visit all the time but we don't notice them because they're very good at staying un-noticed and the time-police make sure of it.

Answer (score 0):

a) You travel to the past.

b) This changes the future. Regardless of how careful you are. Even displaced air molecules count.

c) Because of this your journey to the past is also changed, at least slightly.

d) a>c sets up a feedback effect. You keep changing the past, which changes the future, which changes the past etc.

e) This feedback loop potentially repeats forever. The only reason this feedback effect would ever stop is if a self-consistent timeline emerges.

f) Therefor, to a outside observer without some godlike hyper-time observational powers the only time travel allowed is ones that result in the time travelers trip not being changed in any way at all by their own actions.
Publicly introducing time travel would almost certainly do that - it would be a well known historic event. Therefor it cant be done. If time travel is possible at all, the trip must be observational only. Or, at least, no changes serious enough to effect the time traveler.

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer I am fully qualified to say that time travel is utterly worthless if you change ANYTHING. Why? Because it creates an infinite loop.

Explanation:

If I want to stop Hitler from committing the Holocaust, I'm going to time travel back and kill him. So, I go back I kill Hitler and stop the Holocaust. Boy, that was easy. Now, IF I didn't cause a parallel dimension, or alternate reality, and assuming I actually changed the timeline I came from, let's follow history, from the death of Hitler.

Hitler dies young, no Holocaust. No history books talking about the Holocaust. I am born, I grow up never knowing about the Holocaust. I invent my time machine, I do something else that isn't killing Hitler, because I never knew about him. Hitler is now not killed in his youth. He grows up and commits the Holocaust.

Rinse & Repeat.

There is some flexibility depending on how time actually works. The way I tend to think about it, time have already happened, so future you stops existing once Hitler is killed (aka the first big change that changes your course to create the time machine and go back). Therefore, the you that wants Hitler dead stops existing entirely, because he "never existed" anymore, only the other you exists, but then he stops existing once he doesn't kill hitler. Aka, the universe just keeps ground hog daying around the time of Hitler's "Death", and the time you would have gone back to kill him in the timeline where is still alive.

However, if your time is always linear, or if your time machine somehow stops you from being affected by the change, you could go forward in time (after killing Hitler), and convince yourself that you have to kill a young Hitler in the past once you invent the time machine. This may be difficult to do depending on how much you have a problem with killing people just because a lunatic who looks like an older you tells you to. If you can convince yourself to go back in time without the Holocaust existing and killing Hitler, you can keep there from being an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find most of the existing time travel theories to be garbage.

I don't think there can be a paradox.  The simple reason is that time is relative.  Let's say you have a personal time travelling device.  You turn it on and are transported back to before you were born.  For whatever reason you take an action that results in the death of your parents.

Current theories would say that one of two things will happen.  Either you have just created a new universe (I think this is cheating) or you cause a paradox and everything either blows up or resets (I think this is lazy thinking).

My theory is that nothing happens to you.  You, and whatever you have with you, still exists because your specific time reference hasn't changed.  You'll still have your memories - after all those are just electrical impulses in your brain.  You'll still be alive.  However, the future will be at least somewhat different when you jump back.

So, to answer the questions:

1. Bans are a waste of time unless you can actually enforce it.  The only possible way to enforce this is if there is a unique energy signature given off by the device that can be tracked by satellite.   Further it would have to be detectable in such a way as to give any enforcement people plenty of time to get there and stop it.
2. Obviously I don't think this is a possibility.
3. Possible, likely even.
4. This item doesn't make sense.  If the past is locked then by definition the future would be too.

Answer (score 0):

When time travel becomes possible, exploring other times and cultures is as popular to them as cell phones and the internet are to us now.  Even though there's such a grand choice of times and places to choose to visit, some have undoubtedly chosen ours.

Why haven't they told us all about it?

We've changed quite a bit physically, and none who have gone back far enough long enough to learn now's human forms has taken this knowledge back to them... for very plot-specific reasons.

To be here, they are in the physical forms they know how to create here, and none of these forms very many people of today can or choose to communicate well enough with yet.

Plus, we are to them, sort of like Australopithecus is to us... 
If we went back in time to visit Lucy, would we try to explain the internet to her, or more likely just expose ourselves to her until she trusts who we are and possibly teach her our most basic communication styles instead?

Answer (score 0):

This question have dozens of answers already but nobody come up with this. So, here goes:

The time-traveller switches on his machine set up to take him 1 year back. He is not sure whether earth would be there in space where he will appear. So his time machine is also a spaceship capable of travelling vast distances in space.

"How far can the earth be from where I will arrive?" he thought. Even after accounting for all known motions - planet around sun, sun around galactic center, galaxy around whatever and so on its all a tiny fraction of speed of light. With his near light-speed capable ship no problem, or so he thought.

Turns out there are more levels of motions than known. Their combined effect been earth *is* travelling at near light-speed. Precisely at one trillionth trillionth part less than light-speed.

Good thing that the time-traveller's spaceship too can travel at near light-speed. More near to light-speed than earth. So he *will* catch up with earth.

The problem is, the time he can go back to is very, very less and thats a hard limit. Its hard limit because (in that universe) earth is already travelling at very near to light-speed. The difference is bound at one side by universal speed limit i.e. speed of light, and at the other side by earth speed.

Consider it like a rather strange criteria for passing an exam. You have to score more than your friend. Only the difference in the numbers will be counted. You can take multiple attempts. When sum of the counted marks of all attempts reach 100 you pass the exam. So, if your friend is brilliant and score 98, 99 marks and the upper limit of marks for both you and him is 100 there would be a lot of attempts by you before you pass the exam, no matter how good you are.

"I will solve this through iterations", he think. "See, I can gain on earth a millionth trillionth part of light-speed in each iteration. If I do enough iterations I can reach earth of as much past as I want. Time dilation would mean even the aggregate time of all iterations would be negligible for me".

Turns out spaceship cannot be ready even in theory for next iteration in zero time. The speed of light limit again. It takes time to send forces to each part of ship. Time much larger than the one millionth trillionth part advantage the spaceship can provide.

So what, make a better ship? Well no ship no matter how advanced can beat the universal speed limit and no ship can be smaller than fundamental particles. Call it inertia if you like but in this universe even the fundamental particles cannot have forces act on them instantly.

Its theorized that the machine takes as much time as it takes because its in an energy intensive area of space - on a planet, near a star, one third of the way from galactic center to its rim. If it could be moved in void between galaxies may be the forces act faster.

It turns out nobody even in distant future is able to successfully place the time machine in void between galaxies - nearest been hundreds of thousands of light years away from earth - AND successfully shoot for earth.

This is how even though time travel will be invented in future we never got visited by any time-traveller.

- All times mentioned are in earth's frame of reference except once when time dilation is discussed.