# If Time travel exists

Tags: time-travel

Time travel hasn't been invented yet. Which sucks:< Who wouldn't want to change their past mistakes. What if it has been invented in the future and people do travel back. However, every time they change something, however minute, an alternate reality is created and the one that we exist in isn't changed. Could this be why, we haven't been visited by time travelers from the future?

P.S. I am asking this because of this [Article](https://mic.com/articles/147150/physicists-have-new-proof-that-backward-time-travel-is-impossible#.QlVfT6qLG) here. And yes, I do know that by the rules of physics, time travel backwards isn't theoretically possible.

Comment: pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I am too lazy to find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If time travel is possible in the future, no matter how distant, why haven't they come back to tell us?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/51210/if-time-travel-is-possible-in-the-future-no-matter-how-distant-why-havent-the)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. Unfortunately I have to vote to close your question because it is not actually about building a world, as detailed in these nifty guidelines: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Please read through those, and you are most welcome with any other question you may have, on building worlds. I would also suggest to post this particular question in the Physics or Philosophy Stack Exchange, because those are more appropriate areas for this kind of questions. :)

Comment: Since this is WorldBuilding, and there are no internal logical holes in your question, it seems like you've answered your own question. It may be useful for you to think through the implications of that and see if you have a question that is more in the bounds of WorldBuilding. "If time travel only makes branching timelines then what's the point" isn't right either... But if you put a little thought into it I'm sure you could think of something that we could help you with. Welcome to the site!

Comment: This is under the assumption that we are on the first branch. If we aren't then the could be why we have been visited by time travelers from the future, but we don't believe them.

Comment: Actually, I'd be completely satisfied if all present and future effects of my past faults were reversed. No need to change the past.

Comment: I think this idea was explored in the X-Men comics at some point.

Answer (score 5):

There is another possibility, Niven's Law of Time Travel

> If the universe of discourse permits the possibility of time travel
>   and of changing the past, then no time machine will be invented in
>   that universe.

Every trip to the past changes the timeline. "Sooner" or "later" some bozo will make a change in the past which will result in time travel not being invented. That timeline will be stable, since no one goes back to alter the past.

Comment: interesting point!

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetically if time travel worked the way you described, we would never know that time travel existed. Every time someone from another time arrived in our time a new branched history would be created and our present would remain unchanged.

But that's basically what you said in your question any way. This is somewhat tautological.

There are,of course, many other objections to time travel such that if it existed we would never know about it. Which is, probably, a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Time travel in the future is already possible... well  electricity and photons do move straight in the future faster than anything

and we humans travel in the future for each second passing but at a slower rate.

However time travel isn't possible,as already pointed out by other users when traveling back in time you automatically cancel the reason you traveled back in time in the first place.

However there are 2 ways in which you could give the illusion of traveling back in time.

1)When traveling back in time you don't actually really go in the past but create a clone of your universe with a different time lane, however it doesn't have any whatsoever effect on the original universe.

So if you go back in time to save the life of someone you will not save them, they will remain dead in your universe but you will create a clone of them in another universe.

2)Dying, being dead could be the philosophical equivalent of traveling back in time. As you didn't exist before your birth you will stop to exist after your death, you  could metaphorically consider dying as returning back to your past black dark and void nothingness-